# Ввод символов с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Тренируюсь и сделал вот такой небольшой пример:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char ch;
        System.out.println("Введите данные в консоль: ");
        ch = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Программа считывает введенные данные с клавиатуры (1 символ) и выводит в консоль.

Стало интересно, и я захотел поменять `char` на `String` и посмотреть как всё будет работать:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String ch;
        System.out.println("Введите данные в консоль: ");
        String = (String) System.in.read();
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Но идея выдала ошибку:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'int' to 'java.lang.String'
```

Я полез в гугл и нашел вот такую информацию:

> Why this is not possible: Because `String` and `Integer` are not in
>   the same `Object` hierarchy.

```
      Object
     /      \
    /        \
String     Integer
```

> The casting which you are trying, works only if they are in the same
>   hierarchy, e.g.

```
   Object
     /
    /
   A
  /
 /
B
```

> In this case, `(A) objB` or `(Object) objB` or `(Object) objA` will work.
>   Hence as others have mentioned already, to convert an integer to
>   string use: `String.valueOf(integer)`, or `Integer.toString(integer)` for
>   primitive, or `Integer.toString()` for the object.

Далее я попробовал сделать вот так:

```
String = String.valueOf(ch) System.in.read(); //выдает ошибку: Variable 'ch' might not have been initialized
```

И вот так:

```
String = Integer.toString(ch) System.in.read();
```

Но ничего так и не заработало. Как мне правильно сделать и в чем проблема?

Comment: `String =` - а где название переменной? `String.valueOf(ch) System.in.read();` - должно быть `String.valueOf((char)System.in.read());`

Comment: Так я же когда с char делал, я просто задекларировал переменную и потом в неё поместил так сказать ввод с клавиатуры, String ch написано же выше

Comment: Тогда надо так и писать: `ch = что-то`. Как компилятор должен догадаться, что речь именно про переменную `ch`? Представьте если бы у вас там было `String ch, ch1;`

Comment: Ваш пример String = String.valueOf((char)System.in.read());  не работает(

Comment: Потому что `String =`, повторюсь, - это недопустимая конструкция. Должно быть название переменной слева от `=`

Comment: 1. Убираете строку `String ch;` 2. Заменяете проблемную строку на `String ch = String.valueOf((char)System.in.read());`

Comment: Я понял о чем вы, но там всё равно как я только не делаю, не работает, вот думаю как правильно сделать, чтобы работало

Comment: Всё работает, но ваш код выдаёт 1 символ (char), а я хотел чтобы выдавало всю строку.

Comment: Это потому что вы с консоли считываете ровно один символ. Добавлю в конец ответ один из вариантов чтения строки целиком

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо, я только не понимаю почему пишет: Required: java.lang.String, а Found: int, откуда вообще int :), если мы напишем вот так:  String ch = System.in.read();

Comment: `String ch = System.in.read();` - нет, так не пишем. Метод `read` возвращает `int`, и его так просто к `String` не привести

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.valueOf` тут не поможет, так как будет возвращать код прочитанного символа в виде строки, а не строку из данного символа

Про вариант:

```
String = String.valueOf(ch) System.in.read();
```

В строке несколько ошибок:

1. Слева от `=` в данном случае должно быть название переменной. Если переменная уже существует (например, `ch`), то достаточно её названия. Если переменная только создаётся, то нужны тип + название
2. `valueOf` нужно брать от считанного значения (`System.in.read()`), а не от не инициализированной переменной
3. Метод [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) возвращает `int`. Если взять [`valueOf` от числа](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)), то вернётся текстовое представление числа. Поэтому нужно число привести к `char`, дабы строка [формировалась из символа](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char))

В итоге если объединить объявление и инициализацию переменной, получается так:

```
String ch = String.valueOf((char)System.in.read());
```

---

Для чтения строк из консоли целиком удобно пользоваться [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)-ом:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.in.read()` читает [только один байт](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()).

Для ввода текста нужно использовать сканнер `System.in`:

```
Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);
```